# Rails no route matches controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to pass both a user id, and a test id to a controller using link_to. Below is my code:

```
<%= link_to(test.name, user_test_result_path(:userd_id => 1, protocol.id)) %>
```

and below are my routes:

[image]

but I keep getting the following error:

[image]

Why is it saying that no route matches :action => show and :controller=>"test_results when according to my routes it does exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude. It says `userd_id` here:

```
<%= link_to(test.name, user_test_result_path(:userd_id => 1, protocol.id)) %>
```

Spelling matters!

Also, where is that:

```
{9=>2...}
```

coming from in your params? I'm guessing you'll have more luck if you do something like:

```
<%= link_to(test.name, user_test_result_path(id: protocol.id, user_id: 1)) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying several different things that's why I had the spelling error. Unfortunately, even if I correct the spelling I still get an error. However your last code works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Awesome! Second time today, right? Feel free to press that happy answer button.

Comment: It is the second time today :). I'm new to Rails and still getting the hang of things. I have 51 seconds before I can accept.

Comment: Super happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be passing a hash to your path helper. If your path has two segments, `:user_id` and `:id`, you would simply invoke `helper_name(user_id, id)`, not `helper_name(user_id: user_id, id)`.

In your case you should be calling

```
user_test_result_path(1, protocol.id)
```

Comment: I could be totally wrong, but I think it's copacetic to pass a hash. But, like I said, I could be whacked. Sorry, if I am.

Comment: @jvillian I think it's more likely that I'm totally wrong

Comment: @jvillian Actually I can't find a single example of a hash being used in [the routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) but that doesn't rule it out. Rails is full of undocumented features.

Comment: Check out https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to. It's all over that place.